# Socket.io connecting many times instead of just once

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have build this app, with express.js, its a basic webapp, but now i want to add a simple messaging system.

I already had built my express app and server like this:

```
const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
```

But as I follow this tutorial on socket.io: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I changed my start.js to this, to use socket.io:

```
const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});

const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

It says on the tutorial that when a user signs up i should see a console log saying: `a user is connected`

However I get one log per frame... not just one per connected user.

Is this behaviour correct with the changes i made.. or should i still be getting still just one log per connected user?

Im also using pug as my templating language, and i have, at the end of my layout file this:

```
block scripts
  script(src=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.MAP_KEY}&libraries=places`)
  script(src="/dist/App.bundle.js")
  script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js")
  script.
    const socket = io()
```

App.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');
require('./handlers/passport');

// create our Express app
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // this is the folder where we keep our pug files
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // we use the engine pug, mustache or EJS work great too

// serves up static files from the public folder. Anything in public/ will just be served up as the file it is
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Takes the raw requests and turns them into usable properties on req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Exposes a bunch of methods for validating data. Used heavily on userController.validateRegister
app.use(expressValidator());

// populates req.cookies with any cookies that came along with the request
app.use(cookieParser());

// Sessions allow us to store data on visitors from request to request
// This keeps users logged in and allows us to send flash messages
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

// // Passport JS is what we use to handle our logins
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// // The flash middleware let's us use req.flash('error', 'Shit!'), which will then pass that message to the next page the user requests
app.use(flash());

// pass variables to our templates + all requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.h = helpers;
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
});

// promisify some callback based APIs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
  next();
});

// After allllll that above middleware, we finally handle our own routes!
app.use('/', routes);

// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
  app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
}

// production error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say `I get one log per frame` ? are you talking about html <iframe> ?

Comment: In fact, I think it's wrong to talk about user connection to socket.io, I prefer talk about client connection. Because a user can display your app on multiple tabs or screens or browser at the same time, then you'll have as many connections as opened tabs (or iframe or browser or screens)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had opened multiple tabs with the app, therefore all the logs where from other tabs being connected.